# How to send wishlist with all details in PDF format via email to login customer Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, quote, pdf, wishlist

I wants to send **wishlist** item with `total` and `subtotal` and `grand total`. i am ready with all of these things but need to send this things to `login email id`.

**Updated**

```
   <div class="my-wishlist">
<!--Button code start-->
        <script>var pfHeaderImgUrl = 'http://www.fakhruddinsouq.com/skin/frontend/base/default/images/logo.png';var pfHeaderTagline = '';var pfdisableClickToDel = 1;var pfHideImages = 0;var pfImageDisplayStyle = 'right';var pfDisablePDF = 0;var pfDisableEmail = 0;var pfDisablePrint = 0;var pfCustomCSS = '';var pfBtVersion='1';(function(){var js,pf;pf=document.createElement('script');pf.type='text/javascript';pf.src='//cdn.printfriendly.com/printfriendly.js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(pf)})();</script><a href="https://www.printfriendly.com" style="color:#6D9F00;text-decoration:none;" class="printfriendly" onclick="window.print();return false;" title="Printer Friendly and PDF"><img style="border:none;-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none;" src="//cdn.printfriendly.com/buttons/printfriendly-pdf-email-button-notext.png" alt="Print Friendly and PDF"/></a>
<!--Button code end-->
        <div class="page-title title-buttons">
            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isRssAllow() && $this->hasWishlistItems()): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getRssUrl($this->getWishlistInstance()->getId()); ?>" class="link-rss"><?php echo $this->__('RSS Feed') ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <h1><?php echo $this->getTitle(); ?></h1>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>

        <form id="wishlist-view-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/update', array('wishlist_id' => $this->getWishlistInstance()->getId())) ?>" method="post">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('top'); ?>
            <div class="fieldset">
                <?php if ($this->hasWishlistItems()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey');?>
                        <?php $this->getChild('items')->setItems($this->getWishlistItems()); ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('items');?>
                        <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('wishlist-table')</script>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p class="wishlist-empty"><?php echo $this->__('You have no items in your quote.') ?></p>
                <?php endif ?>
                <div class="buttons-set buttons-set2">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('control_buttons');?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <form id="wishlist-allcart-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/allcart') ?>" method="post">
            <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
            <div class="no-display">
                <input type="hidden" name="wishlist_id" id="wishlist_id" value="<?php echo $this->getWishlistInstance()->getId() ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="qty" id="qty" value="" />
            </div>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            var wishlistForm = new Validation($('wishlist-view-form'));
            var wishlistAllCartForm = new Validation($('wishlist-allcart-form'));

            function calculateQty() {
                var itemQtys = new Array();
                $$('#wishlist-view-form .qty').each(
                    function (input, index) {
                        var idxStr = input.name;
                        var idx = idxStr.replace( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
                        itemQtys[idx] = input.value;
                    }
                );

                $$('#qty')[0].value = JSON.stringify(itemQtys);
            }

            function addAllWItemsToCart() {
                calculateQty();
                wishlistAllCartForm.form.submit();
            }
        //]]>
        </script>
       </div>
```

Comment: In order email or else ?

Comment: without login we cant add item in wishlist so i wants to send wishlist item detail to login email i.e registered email id

Comment: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/wishlist-notification-3.html try this

Comment: this extension compatible only up to magento 1.8 by the way this is not my requirement. when clicking on share wishlist button all wishlist item detail will be send to  currently login customer

Answer (score 0):

If you'll use this button code

https://www.printfriendly.com/button

just generate code and put in your wishlist product page and when you'll click on this button this'll give you send all whishlist product details to emails. check this one if it'll help you.

Comment: after adding this code in to wishlist age i am not able to see button there.

Comment: why not, wishislist products page need login access ?

Comment: it working for generate pdf but when sending email email received but content not showing

Comment: yes button  working

Comment: email is empty ? attach option is showing in email ?

Comment: pdf not showing wishlist item and i do not need to show PrintFriendly url in email after open pdf

Comment: No, this button 'll give you option whatever you want to show, i think you are using this button on wrong place. put inside main div of wishlist item section.

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: if anything coming extra you can hide in your css file, which file link you are mentioned in button code.

Comment: i have added screenshoot after clicking on attach pdf link it showing like this and it should not be show pdffriendly text anywhere please see updated question

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ge0y17

Comment: See in this screenshot, i'm showing my products according to whatever i want. your are missing div section, i think and you can hide extra content in your css file like as display none all of those extra css classes.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ge11ld in this screenshot you can see what i mean, where i'm showing this button. which div content i want in pdf  i'll use code inside that div.

Comment: please see my updated section in question. this is my wishlist content div

Comment: please see my div and update your code in that

Comment: https://prnt.sc/gefd25
https://prnt.sc/gefd77

Comment: i know this is working from your end but update this code in my div which i have mentioned in question

Comment: @Neeya you are generating pdf successfully ?

Comment: if email option is not working then choose another options, you can add there 1 more email button and create custom email form on popup, when customer click on that button then all fields filled automatically just he'll attach his pdf file.

Comment: pdf is generate successfully but i wants to send same pdf via email

Comment: after sending mail it is not showing pdf

Comment: aslo i do not have to show printfriedly word anywhere

Comment: in email there is showing sender email printfriendly i wants to my custom email id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64739/discussion-between-wajahat-bashir-and-neeya).